# How to store questions under each category and fetch the results to view based on the percentage each categories got in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I was trying to store answers for each question category and retrieve the result to view by iterating by categories and questions.

Here's my controller method for storing the answer of a user:

```
public function store3(Request $request, $id) {

        $questions = Question::with('category')->get();

        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $answers = $request->input('answer');

            $passCountByCategory = [];

            foreach ($questions as $question) {
                $answer = $answers[$question->id] ?? null;

                if ($answer === 'Yes') {
                    $categoryId = $question->category->id;
                    $passCountByCategory[$categoryId] = ($passCountByCategory[$categoryId] ?? 0) + 1;
                } elseif ($answer === 'No') {
                    $categoryId = $question->category->id;
                    $passCountByCategory[$categoryId] = ($passCountByCategory[$categoryId] ?? 0);
                } else {
                    echo "You did not choose any options";
                }
            }

            $categoryCount = count($passCountByCategory);
            $categoryPassCount = 0;

            foreach ($passCountByCategory as $passCount) {
                if ($passCount >= 2) {
                    $categoryPassCount++;
                }
            }

            $result = ($categoryPassCount == $categoryCount) ? 'You Passed' : 'You Failed';

            $app_name = UserApps::where('app_id', $id)->value('app_name');


            $appStatus = ($result === 'You Passed') ? 'Certified' : 'Unapproved';
            UserApps::where('app_id', $id)->update(['status' => $appStatus]);

            $resultStatus = ($result === 'You Passed') ? 'Passed' : 'Failed';

            $resultData = [

                'app_id' => $id,
                'app_name' => $app_name,
                'pass_count' => $categoryPassCount,
                'total_count' => $categoryCount,
                'result' => $resultStatus
            ];

            $overallPercentage = 0;

            $resultData['category_results'] = [];

            foreach ($passCountByCategory as $categoryId => $passCount) {
                $category = Category::find($categoryId);
                $categoryResult = $passCount;
                $categoryStatus = ($categoryResult >= 2) ? 'Passed' : 'Failed';
                $categoryPercentage = ($categoryResult / 3) * 100;

                $resultData['category_results'][$categoryId] = [

                    'category_name' => $category->name,
                    'pass_count' => $categoryResult,
                    'total_count' => count($category->questions),
                    'category_status' => $categoryStatus,
                    'percentage' => $categoryPercentage
                ];

                $overallPercentage += $categoryPercentage;
            }

            $overallPercentage /= $categoryCount;
            $resultData['percentage'] = $overallPercentage;

            if (empty($resultData['category_results'])) {
                $resultData['category_results'] = [];
            }

            TestResults::create($resultData);

            return redirect()->route('question_result', ['id' => $id])->with('categoryResults', $resultData);
        }
    }
```

then here's my controller method to show the result to user after submitting:

```
 public function testResultShow(Request $request, $app_id) {
        
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $results = TestResults::where('app_id', $app_id)->first();

            if (!$results) {
                return Redirect::route('user_apps')->with('error', 'No result found!');
            }

            $title = $results->app_name . " Test Result";

            $app_name = $results->app_name ?? '';
            $app_id = $results->app_id ?? '';

            $categories = Category::all();
            $questions = Question::with('category')->get();

            $passCountByCategory = [];
            foreach ($questions as $question) {
                $answer = $request->input('answers.' . $question->id);

                if ($answer === 'Yes') {
                    $categoryId = $question->category->id;
                    $passCountByCategory[$categoryId] = ($passCountByCategory[$categoryId] ?? 0) + 1;
                } elseif ($answer === 'No') {
                    $categoryId = $question->category->id;
                    $passCountByCategory[$categoryId] = ($passCountByCategory[$categoryId] ?? 0);
                } else {
                    echo "You did not choose any options";
                }
            }

            $categoryCount = count($passCountByCategory);
            $categoryPassCount = 0;

            foreach ($passCountByCategory as $passCount) {
                if ($passCount >= 2) {
                    $categoryPassCount++;
                }
            }

            $overallResult = ($categoryPassCount == $categoryCount)
                ? ['result' => 'You Passed', 'passCount' => $categoryPassCount, 'totalCount' => $categoryCount]
                : ['result' => 'You Failed', 'passCount' => $categoryPassCount, 'totalCount' => $categoryCount];

            $categoryResults = [];
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $categoryResult = [
                    'name' => $category->name,
                    'pass_count' => $passCountByCategory[$category->id] ?? 0,
                    'total_count' => $results->total_count_by_category($category->id),
                    'percentage' => $results->percentage_by_category($category->id),
                    'result' => ($passCountByCategory[$category->id] ?? 0) >= 2 ? 'Passed' : 'Failed',
                ];

                $categoryResults[] = $categoryResult;
            }

            $planss = PlanLevels::all();
            $user = Auth::user();

            return view('user.showresult', compact(

                'title',
                'passCountByCategory',
                'overallResult',
                'categoryResults',
                'planss',
                'user',
                'app_id',
                'app_name',
                'results'
            ));

        } else {
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'You must log in first');
        }
    }
```

Here's my view table:

```
   <tbody>

                            @foreach ($categoryResults as $categoryResult)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $categoryResult['name'] }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $categoryResult['pass_count'] }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $categoryResult['total_count'] }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $categoryResult['result'] }}</td>
                                    <td class="tb-col-end">{{ $categoryResult['percentage'] }}%</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>

                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"></td>
                                <td colspan="2" class="tb-col tb-col-end">TOTAL SCORE:</td>
                                <td>{{ $results->total_count }} question passed</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"></td>
                                <td colspan="2" class="tb-col tb-col-end">OVERALL RESULT:</td>
                                <td>{{ $results->percentage }}%</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"></td>
                                <td colspan="2" class="tb-col tb-col-end">OVERRAL STATUS:</td>
                                <td>
                                    @if ($results->percentage < 66)
                                        <p class="text-danger">Retake the test</p>
                                    @elseif ($results->percentage < 66.66)
                                        <p class="text-warning">Review your weak areas</p>
                                    @else
                                        <p class="text-success">You are certified!</p>
                                    @endif
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
```

The answer to the questions is always YES. and I have a request from the form to get the answer[] (I did not save the value of the answer in the database.)

Here's the result I was getting after taking the test and trying to view the resul(screesnhot):
[image: the current result I am getting]

Note that all three categories show the same value. I want each category to show its own percentage and result based on the questions they have.

Comment: Please double-check the tags you have in use. Even while there might be some relation to PHP or mysql, the context seems to be entirely Laravel. Could you please clarify how it is related to PHP or MySql in your question? Until then I've removed those two tags, you can always [edit] as well yourself.